# Change JButton look to custom picture

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Is it possible to change the look of JButton to a custom picture? I want to use this picture as the button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMQMX.png instead of: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXKUF.png

I have tried myself without succeed. Please help me! :)

Here is my code:

```
    package launcher;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;

public class Launcher extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JPanel contentPane;

    static Point mouseDownCompCoords;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    mouseDownCompCoords = null;
                    final Launcher frame = new Launcher();
                    frame.setResizable(false);
                    frame.setUndecorated(true);
                    frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 255, 0, 0));
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
                        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                            mouseDownCompCoords = null;
                        }

                        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                            mouseDownCompCoords = e.getPoint();
                        }

                        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                        }

                        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                        }

                        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        }
                    });

                    frame.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
                        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                        }

                        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                            Point currCoords = e.getLocationOnScreen();
                            frame.setLocation(currCoords.x - mouseDownCompCoords.x,
                                    currCoords.y - mouseDownCompCoords.y);
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Launcher() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 841, 593);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel Design = new JLabel("New label");
        Design.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Pictures\\Launcher2.png"));
        Design.setBounds(-158, -22, 1047, 592);
        contentPane.add(Design);

        JButton Playnow = new JButton("");
        Playnow.setOpaque(false);
        Playnow.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Pictures\\Playnow.png"));

        Playnow.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                //Playnow.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Pictures\\PlaynowHover.png"));
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                //Playnow.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Pictures\\PlaynowHover.png"));
            }
        });
        Playnow.setBounds(258, 442, 301, 46);
        contentPane.add(Playnow);

        JButton Exit = new JButton("");
        Exit.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                final Launcher frame = new Launcher();
                frame.dispose();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        Exit.setBounds(766, 60, 19, 17);
        contentPane.add(Exit);


    }
}
```

I fixed it. There was something wrong with the picture thats why I couldnt see it...

Comment: Do you want to change the icons based on the mouse events?

Comment: Well I want the button to be looked like as the first picture I saw and when someone hovers the mouse or click the button it changes picture to another.

Comment: unrelated: a) Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them b) never-ever do any manual sizing/locating of components, that's the exclusive task of a suitable LayoutManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    try {
        Playnow.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMQMX.png")));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

this worked for me at the moment when i tried using ur code. however, if you wanna load it locally, you should try:

```
Playnow.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("test.png")));
```

and test.png is in the same directory as the class file this code is in.

hope this helps :)

Comment: Hmm I tried the first code and it worked but only for that URL. I tried another URL and it didnt work. Also, load the picture locally didnt work either :(

Comment: the image has to be in the same package, in the case, launcher. also, i hope you changed "test.png" to whatever the image name is lol ;)

Comment: and just so there's no confusion, this code is the one right after: Playnow.setOpaque(false);

Comment: I do have the image in the package, I changed test.png to correct  name and I put the codet after Playnow.setOpaque(false); The image will still not pop up :/

Comment: hmmm, that's very interesting cuz i ran it several times and it worked for me and that was all i changed in your code. do you mind posting your updated code?

Comment: change the code inside mouseClicked and moseEntered to this:
Playnow.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("PlaynowHover.png")));

also make sure PlaynowHover.png is in the same package.

Comment: I must have done something wrong because the button doesnt change at all... Still looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/RCewXW4.png

Comment: damn, this is so weird. ummmmmm idk cuz i'm running it on eclipse as well and it works just fine. it's not throwing any errors right?

Comment: well damn dude, i'm sry but i'm completely stumped at this point lol just so you know, i'm running it on linux using eclipse with jdk 7. your code looks fine. i just don't know why its not showing the image properly >.<

Comment: Could you look over Teamviewer if thats possible? Whats your email so I can send you my details?

Answer (score 0):

(I can't write comments yet so i write it as am awnser) I am not sure if this applies here, too but when i tried to change the icon of a Jlabel in my project, i had to set it invisible and after changing the icon visible again. Maybe it works if you try it like that.

Comment: _i had to set it invisible_ then something elsewhere goes severely wrong in your context ... All done correctly, there's **never** any reason for a invisible/visible cycle when setting a property of a component.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ImageIcon ic=new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Daniel/Pictures/Playnow.png")
JButton Playnow = new JButton(ic);
Playnow.setOpaque(false);
```

Comment: Didnt work. This is really mysterious :O I found out that it only works with other pictures, not the one I made for the button 0_o